# XSLFO - displaying header and footer

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Am converting xml to PDF using XSL FO. I want to display Header contents in the below format

```
Header Contents

Line 1               Line 1.1
Line 2               Line 1.2
Line 2               Line 1.3
```

Right now, am trying with the below lines of code :

```
 <fo:block> Line 1 </fo:block> <fo:block>   Line 1.1 </fo:block>
 <fo:block> Line 2 </fo:block> <fo:block>   Line 1.2 </fo:block>
 <fo:block> Line 3 </fo:block> <fo:block>   Line 1.3 </fo:block>
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly, adding the header content? Or the layout of the "lines"? That looks more like tabular data to me so using a table with three rows of two columns, the first left aligned, the second right aligned, might give you what you want.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Yes, am looking for the layout lines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want locate "Line 1" aligned to the left of the header and "Line 1.1" aligned to the right of the header, there is no need to use tabular layout. Below example uses `fo:leader` object to accomplish this requirement.

```
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" font-size="9pt">
        <fo:block space-before="2mm" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after="2mm"  border-bottom="2pt solid green">
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Line 1<fo:leader leader-length.maximum="100%" leader-pattern="space"/>Line 1.1</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Line 2<fo:leader leader-length.maximum="100%" leader-pattern="space"/>Line 1.2</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">Line 3<fo:leader leader-length.maximum="100%" leader-pattern="space"/>Line 1.3</fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
```

The FOP formatting result:
[image: FOP Formatting result]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a tabular layout then:

```
        <fo:table width="100%">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block> Line 1 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right"> Line 1.1 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block> Line 2 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right"> Line 1.2 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block> Line 3 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right"> Line 1.3 </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```